# GWT: How do I get the child widget of a com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget?

Tags: gwt, widget

I'm using GWT 2.4.  Given a com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget, how do I get the first child widget?  For example, if the Widget represents a `<div>`, I'd like to know the first thing within the `<div>`.  There is no guarantee that there will be a child widget, but if there is, I'd like to know how to get it.

All I know is this generic object class.  I'm not guaranteed that this will be a widget like a FlowPanel or anything else, even though those are possibilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GWT widgets that can have children implement the [`HasWidgets`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasWidgets.html) interface:

```
Widget getFirstChild(Widget parent) {
  if (parent instanceof HasWidgets) {
    Iterator<Widget> iter = ((HasWidgets) parent).iterator();
    return (iter != null && iter.hasNext()) ? iter.next() : null;
  }

  return null;
}
```